# Handling invalid data in Django rest_framework's serializer custom fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently extending Django rest_framework's `serializers.WritableField` to (no surprise) translate data into a more front-end friendly format. My code looks like this:

```
class FooField(serializers.WritableField):
    def from_native(self, value):
        return #makeFoo

    def to_native(self, value):
        return #undoFoo
```

then I have a serializer which looks like this:

```
class FooUsingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    the_field = FooField(source='a_model_field')

    def validate_the_field(self,attrs):
        #validate result

        return attrs
```

The problem is, from_native is called before validate_the_field is called and the original data isn't even passed to validate_the_field, so if garbage data is passed in (in my specific case, it would be anything that wasn't a valid date) instead of validate_the_field catching it, I will return a 500 error. I considered something like this:

```
def from_native(self, value):
    try:
        return #makeFoo
    except:
        return #a flag to show that the data wasn't valid
```

But this just feels like a hacky way to handle the problem, especially since Django rest_framework is usually pretty clean. Does anyone know a way of handling garbage-data that works well with from_native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you take a look into the DRF code, you'll see that many fields that extend `WritableField` are validated like this. Let's take `DecimalField`, for example:

```
class DecimalField(WritableField):

    def from_native(self, value):
        ...
        try:
            value = Decimal(value)
        except DecimalException:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'])
        return value
```

Comment: Very nice! Not only do they raise ValidationErrors, but in other places they even call perform_validation directly from BaseSerializer.from_native() Thanks!